# longer stack trace for segmentation fault?

Tags: segmentation-fault, gdb, stack-trace, intel-fortran, traceback

ifort compiled with "-traceback" prints only 10 lines but the segmentation occurred in an inner subroutine that is at least 10 layers within.  So, exactly routine where seg-fault occurred isn't displayed.

Its MPI program and running gdb isn't a viable option..

any help?

thnx

Comment: Two common causes of segfaults in Fortran programs are (i) attempting to address an array element outside the bounds of the array and (ii) mismatching procedure actual and dummy arguments.  `ifort` can, generally, diagnose both these problems if you compile with the correct options (for what they are, see the documentation). Failing that, and leaving the advice to use `gdb` to one side, do you have an installation of either TotalView or DDT both of which can be used for debugging MPI programs ?

Comment: I only knew about (i) for which I added "-check all" (actually "-check bounds") but couldn't find any problem.  It is actually related to (ii). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> MPI program and running gdb isn't a viable option.

Why not? You should enable core dumps, get a core, and analyse it with GDB.